# Can one always find a basis of global vector fields $X_0 , \ldots , X_n$ for the tangent space $T_p M$ for a manifold $M$?

Tags: global-analysis

I know that locally that is possible, as for local coordinates $x_i$ $(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i})_{i \in I}$ spans $T_p M$ and therefore, one gets a local vector field. How do I extend this one?

Comment: Since you are asking for the possibility of always finding such a "global basis", do you have one example at least where it is possible?

Comment: I was reading in Bredon, where he just takes a basis $X_0 , \ldots , X_n$ for $T_e G$, where $G$ is a Lie group.

Comment: Assuming you want smooth vector fields, then no it's not always possible. For Lie groups, since left multiplication is a diffeomorphism, you can take a basis for the tangent space at the identity, and "translate" it to a basis at every point. This defines smooth vector fields that form a basis at every point.

Answer (score 4):

In general, you are not even guaranteed to find **one** global vector field which never vanishes. This is the case for $M=S^{2n}$ ([hairy ball theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairy_ball_theorem)).